# Passing PHP Variables to File included in Wordpress project

Tags: php, wordpress

For the below code I need to write all the php variable data on the invoice.php file so the I can get the updated file with dynamic data for the converted invoice.pdf.

```
$invoice_price = get_user_meta( $user_id, "_issuem_leaky_paywall_live_price", TRUE);
$invoice_package = get_user_meta( $user_id, "_issuem_leaky_paywall_live_description", TRUE);
$invoice_number = get_user_meta( $user_id, "_issuem_leaky_paywall_live_subscriber_id", TRUE);
$date = date ('DD-MM-YY');

include ( ABSPATH . 'invoice.php');
require ( ABSPATH . 'pdfcrowd.php');

try
  {
  // create an API client instance
  $client = new Pdfcrowd("apiname", "apikey");
 // converted php file and store the generated PDF inside uploads  
 $fd = fopen( ABSPATH . 'wp-content/uploads/invoice.pdf', 'wb');
 $client->convertFile( ABSPATH . 'invoice.php', $fd );
 fclose($fd);
```

It's only converted the static content and no PHP variable data passing for the invoice.

Comment: I've not used PDF crowd but it looks like you are sending the convertFile method the original, unaltered version of the file invoice.php. I think you would need to create a new html file after the include statement that would contain all the php variables in place. Then use that file as the first argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I think using converHtml would work better for you. You could use

```
ob_start();
include ( ABSPATH . 'invoice.php');
$content = ob_get_clean();
```

Then use $content as first arg in

```
$client->convertHtml($content,$fd);
```

Here's the doc where I got this:
http://pdfcrowd.com/web-html-to-pdf-php/#reference

Comment: Hi user3080408, Suddenly again the content not getting the php value on the live dev site although it works on local fine, Any clue ?

Comment: Can you post your code exactly as it is on your live site? Generally speaking here, if you move code from one server to another and the behavior changes, you look at the environment of the new server to see if something is interfering.